# Custom background on UITableViewCell on tvOS

Tags: swift, uitableview, tvos

I'm trying to set a custom background for a focused UITableViewCell. By default the cell gets a shadow and the size is slightly increased which is a behavior I completely want to remove and just have a normal background color when focused.

BTW I'm using Swift 2.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the answer!

I had to subclass UITableViewCell and override the didUpdateFocusInContext like the following:

```
override func didUpdateFocusInContext(context: UIFocusUpdateContext, withAnimationCoordinator coordinator: UIFocusAnimationCoordinator) {

    if context.nextFocusedView === self
    {
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor()
    }
    else{
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    }
}
```